# Updated MiKTeX files, now miktex-xelatex.exe "-aux-directory=DIR" and "-output-directory=DIR"options suddenly conflict?

Tags: xetex, miktex, miktex-update

EDIT3: As of 2017-01-09, the bug has been fixed (see: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2565/)

EDIT2: After contacting the miktex-users mailing list, it appears this is a current bug.  Until it is resolved, please see my answer below for a workaround.

---

I have been using the following in a batch file to build my LaTeX documents for many months without issue:

```
@miktex-xelatex.exe -enable-enctex -enable-etex -enable-installer -enable-mltex 
-enable-pipes -enable-write18 -synctex=1 -aux-directory=_build_files 
-output-directory=./ "%1.tex"
```

Today, I updated (both as user and as admin) MiKTeX, which has a bunch of `.exe` file updates/removals.  Everything builds more or less properly, but the `-aux-directory` option seems to have just completely stopped working when `-output-directory` is present.  It seems `-output-directory` now acts like `-aux-directory` **AND** overrides it.

I had been using `-aux-directory` for all the build files, but still wanted `-output-directory` for putting the `.pdf` and `.synctex.gz` output files.  But, with the update, I can user *either*

```
@miktex-xelatex.exe -enable-enctex -enable-etex -enable-installer -enable-mltex 
-enable-pipes -enable-write18 -synctex=1 -aux-directory=_build_files "%1.tex"
```

*or*

```
@miktex-xelatex.exe -enable-enctex -enable-etex -enable-installer -enable-mltex 
-enable-pipes -enable-write18 -synctex=1 -output-directory=_build_files "%1.tex"
```

The problem here is that neither of these methods places the `.pdf` and `.synctex.gz` output files in the same directory as the `.tex` file

It seems like this must be a bug?  (it was working before the 2016-12-23 version of the files)

EDIT: It may have been introduced prior to 2016-12-23.  After thinking about it... I'm not sure exactly how recently I updated MiKTeX and packages.  Therefore, it might have be 1-2 versions earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a *proper* solution, because I still believe this is a bug.  However, if anyone else is having the problem, hopefully it will help them handle it until the `.exe` is updated.

I modified the `miktex-xelatex.exe` call in the `.bat` file to (ie. removed the `-output-directory` option:

```
@miktex-xelatex.exe -enable-enctex -enable-etex -enable-installer -enable-mltex 
-enable-pipes -enable-write18 -synctex=1 -aux-directory=_build_files "%1.tex"
```

I also needed to add the following to options to copy the `.pdf` and `.synctex.gz` output files from the build folder back to the `.tex` folder.

```
@copy /Y "OUTPUT_DIR\%1.pdf" "%1.pdf"
@copy /Y "OUTPUT_DIR\%1.synctex.gz" "%1.synctex.gz"
```

Hope this helps someone!